# RAM usage after program loading - mismatch with TOP statistics

Tags: linux, gcc, ram

I have expected that after running program the top utility will show memory (VIRT column) used by my program equal to or greater than size on the disk. I was surprised when the result was different - the file size on the disc turned out to be greater than the top one showed. Could you explain what is wrong in my expectations....
P.S. Application is native built with gcc.

Comment: Could you explain why you would expect this? Unless the application does nothing except return immediately there are usually shared libraries, data sections etc etc that use memory. And if you expected the used memory to be more than the file, why now surprised that it is more?

Comment: It was my mistake - look my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Not all parts of an executable file get mapped into memory when you run it.

If you examine your executable with `readelf -WS <executable>` (assuming elf executable format) you can see the list of file sections. Only sections with flag `A (alloc)` get loaded.

Sections starting with `.debug`, for example, do not get mapped, unless it runs under a debugger, and these sections are often the largest.